# Include multiple files in index.php

Tags: indexing, include, directory, root

I've got my site builed with multiple folders and files. Like:

index.php
includes/config.php
memberscript/login.php
memberscript/register.php
memberscript/profile.php
memberscript/change-pass.php

What is the most easy way to include all the files from the memberscript folder into index.php without using switch $_GET statements where i have to case each of the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it is the best to use automatic class loader like [Symfony2 ClassLoader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/introduction.html). It is a very convenient way to load only the files you need in each of the request.

If you are still coding in procedural PHP it is the best time to learn [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

There are numerous frameworks which enforces you to code that way like [Symfony2 (for large projects)](http://symfony.com/), [Silex (for small websites)](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and many other like CakePHP, ZendFramework, CodeIgniter etc.

By using one of these frameworks your code will be easy to understand by any programmer and easy to maintain.

Comment: Symfony ClassLoader link is broken. Proper link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/introduction.html